# Unable to Zipalign apk

Tags: android, zip, alignment

Ok so I published a live wallpaper I made with a Live Wallpaper Creator and published it to the Market. I want to add a zipaligned new version of the LWP but I have no idea what to do.

I tried app to market and zipaligned a new version LWP I made, however the problem is Google Play Market will not allow me to update my apk file because the live wallpaper creator used  a different signing key.

My question is how can I go about Ziplaligning my apk I created with the LWP program without resigning it so I can update in the Market?  I just want to "zipalign" it.

*Note ive tried using Eclipse zipalign tool, but couldnt figure out how to do it, since the apk wasnt created with Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Just run `zipalign` on your APK. There's an official [guide to signing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#align) manually which includes a section on zipalign:

```
zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk your_project_name.apk
```

Comment: Im getting Error Unknown Flag -4     What folder does my apk file need to be in, if im using SDK to do the manual zipalign process?